# Why a property access like a function in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

see the small code as follows

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
        incrementClickCounter : function() {
            var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
            this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
        }
    };
</script>
```

`numberOfClicks`  has been defined as a property in view model and when it is accessed from `incrementClickCounter()` function then bracket has been used like this way `this.numberOfClicks()` but why just do not understand.

what would be the harm if we write the `incrementClickCounter` function like below way.

```
incrementClickCounter : function() 
{
    this.numberOfClicks=this.numberOfClicks+1;
}
```

looking for suggestion and guidance. thanks

Comment: You can write it like that, and your data model would update as you'd expect (if you inspected the numberOfClicks attribute of the viewModel object, Knockout aside), but there is nothing in that alone to tell your UI to update. That is a function of binding KO observables.

Comment: i just like to know why a property is accessed like a function `this.numberOfClicks()` rather can't we write like this way `this.numberOfClicks` ? why should we give bracket at the end of property name ? please put some light. thanks

Comment: Because `this.numberOfClicks` is a function.

Comment: numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0) has been declared as observable array? so any property declared as observable array need to access like function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The knockout is using functional style for accessing properties is because it has support for the ancient browsers like:

> Supports all mainstream browsers, even ancient ones
>
> IE6+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome, Opera, Safari (desktop/mobile)

Answer (score 1):

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

> How can KO know when parts of your view model change? Answer: you need to declare your model properties as observables, because these are special JavaScript objects that can notify subscribers about changes, and can automatically detect dependencies.

If you look at [the source of `ko.observable()`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observable.js) you'll find it's doing a lot more than simply setting it to a value.

Comment: what i asked and what u answered. i was talking about property access style type and what u answer.

Comment: i just like to know why a property is accessed like a function `this.numberOfClicks()` rather can't we write like this way `this.numberOfClicks` ? why should we give bracket at the end of property name ? please put some light. thanks

Comment: if still my question is not clear then ask me. thanks

Comment: @Mou Because `this.numberOfClicks` is a function. Run it in your console and you'll get the function code. The function needs to be *executed* to output the observable value.

Comment: @Mou the design choice to use functions to read and write observable values was made to support old browsers (IE<9).  JavaScript language support of getters & setters allows for more natural code while still allowing observables to work.  Knockout's creator Steve Sanderson put together Knockout-ES5 with this functionality as a proof of concept.  I don't recommend using that code for your own website today but I mention it here if you want to learn more about how Knockout works. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/

Answer (score -1):

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.name=ko.observableArray('my name');
    alert(this.name())
    this.name1=ko.observableArray(['my name111'])
    alert(this.name1())
    this.name2=ko.observableArray([1,2,3])
    alert(this.name2())
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```